# "of his being active" or "of him being active"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Should I use 'of him' or 'of his' in front of 'being + adjective' or 'being + past participle'?
For example:

> Throughout this year Brian has maintained a rather laidback attitude
> at times bordering on laziness. Occasional glimpses **of his being
> engaged** came only during team competitions when Brian couldn’t escape
> from the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk about glimpses of the person himself, you use **him** - an object pronoun referring to the person himself.

If you want to talk about glimpses of the state a person is in, you use **his** a determiner that refers to some property of the person, because you are talking about **his** state.

In the sentence that you quoted, Brain (should that be Brian?) is normally lazy, and only becomes involved in things (is engaged) during team competitions.

You can see Brain the person any time that you look at him. The [glimpses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glimpse) are on the rare occasions when his state is engaged, so you get glimpses of **his** being engaged.

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate a bit? I kind of don't see the difference between glimpses of the person himself and glimpses of the state that person is in.

Comment: What do you think the passage in my question is talking about? Is it about the person or about that person's state?

Comment: @brilliant I have expanded my answer.

Comment: I see now. Thank you.